# 2004 Suzuki Aerio running hot

Tags: radiator, temperature, hose, radiator-overflow

I just put in a new radiator, new cap, new hoses. My hoses are swelling. And when then cap is off the radiator if foams. The car is not overheating.  Also the overfill hose is pushing out air.   But its def running hot and wondering why the radiator hoses would swell like that and why air coming from overfill hose. Please any advice.

Comment: Its not showing its overheating

Comment: I ran the car with the cap off and let it bubble and kept adding fluid to the radiator. Sens then today the hose isnt quite as firm. Could the water pump be going out?